# Page A has a different size than Page B, same stylesheet used

Tags: html, css

The size of all the elements on Page A differs from those of Page B, and the size of the elements in Page B are identical to Page C, D, E and so on. I've gone through the code and checked the tags, as well as specific tags that might affect that Page A. I've also linked all the pages to the same CSS stylesheet.

Are there any other possibilities that I may have missed?

[Page A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRiYC.png)

[Page B](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLmLb.png)

Comment: If the content on pages A and B is different, the size of the files will be different. A difference in filesize between two files is **very** common, and not a bad thing. Why are you concerned about the filesizes? Are you having a specific problem with them?

Comment: I didn't make it clear, sorry. I'm talking about the size of the elements, such as the text, images in general. They have all increased in size.

Comment: Can you add the codes so that we can check? 
Besides, there is possibility that you changed the browser size in page A, and the rest of pages stay the same. Try "CTRL+0" in page A and see what happens.

Comment: All of the code?

Comment: No, not all the code. Please give us a **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**.

Comment: I have no idea how it happened, but it fixed itself. **Edit: It was the zoom.** Thanks @Minwu Yu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that is the zoom setting in your browser. Adjust the Zoom setting and reset to default size.

See:
https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-adjust-chromes-default-zoom-settings/